# Subtracting specific datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am required to find the calculate the 'time to maturity' by finding the difference between 'maturity' and 'trd_exctn_dt' as shown below.

If I had the following sample data:

| cusip_id | trd_exctn_dt | maturity | time_to_maturity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0007TAA2 | 2015-01-26 | 2023-05-15 | 3031 days |
| 0007TAA2 | 2015-03-26 | 2023-05-15 | 2972 days |
| 0007TAA2 | 2015-05-01 | 2023-05-15 | 2936 days |
| 0007TAA2 | 2015-07-27 | 2023-05-15 | 2849 days |

My desired output would be:

| cusip_id | trd_exctn_dt | maturity | time_to_maturity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0007TAA2 | 2015-05-01 | 2023-05-15 | 2936 days |

For this specific cusip_id, because the maturity date is in the 5th month, I am looking for the trd_exctn_dt in the 5th month, in order to calculate the time to maturity. However, I want to do this for several bond issues, where 'maturity' will not necessarily occur within the 5th month'. For example, for another bond issue, the maturity date may be 2023-11-06, therefore I would be looking for the trd_exctn_dt in the 11th month for that bond issue.

Any ideas on how I would do this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that you want every row where `maturity` month equals `trd_exctn_dt` month.

**Code**

```py
df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]  # Remove whitespace from column names

# Convert to datetime
df['trd_exctn_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['trd_exctn_dt']) 
df['maturity'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity'])

df['time_to_maturity'] = df['maturity'] - df['trd_exctn_dt']  # If you need to recalculate
df[df['trd_exctn_dt'].dt.month == df['maturity'].dt.month]  # Filter for same month in both columns
```

**Output**

```
    cusip_id    trd_exctn_dt    maturity    time_to_maturity
2   0007TAA2    2015-05-01      2023-05-15  2936 days
```